# Generate a Barcode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to create an app that will generate a bar code. So far I cannot get it to work properly. I get two errors:

-Error  CS0118  'generate' is a namespace but is used like a type   generate;
-Error  CS1955  Non-invocable member 'MemoryStream' cannot be used like a method.   generate

Please see the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace barcode
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String barcode = pole.Text;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 150);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                Font ofont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 20);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush White = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(White, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", ofont, black, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = MemoryStream()) 
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                box.Image = bitmap;
                box.Height = bitmap.Height;
                box.Width = bitmap.Width;
            }
        }
    }
    }



PROGRAM.cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace generate
    {
        static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new generate());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `using (MemoryStream ms = MemoryStream())` should be `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())` - you are instantiating an object not calling a local method

Comment: As for the generate error, cannot tell, maybe we dont have all the code? I dont see the word generate in your code anywhere

Comment: Sorry, just added the code from program.cs

Comment: You are trying to instantiate a namespace name. Use this instead: `Application.Run(new Form1());`. Also, change `Namespace generate` to `Namespace barcode` so its in the same namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
Application.Run(new generate());
```

To this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Also, you're going to have to import the namespace of `Form1` to your Program.cs file with the following line

```
using barcode;
```

As for the `MemoryStream` error, change this line:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = MemoryStream())
```

To this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
```

What happened here was you failed to initialize the instance of `MemoryStream` with the keyword `new` so the compiler was treating it as a method

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you for your help. The app works now, it does generate an image but it does not create a barcode. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @Truex I would recommend posting a new question with all important data relating to your new issue. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: cheers mate, I have only just posted another question. Once again, appreciate your help